# Distributed Interactive Simulation- how to set alternative entity type?

Tags: java, simulation

I am developing a Java program that will be used to manage the DIS (Distributed Interactive Simulation) information that is being sent over a network. The information is all being sent in PDUs (Protocol Datagram Units), and my program is currently receiving each PDU that is sent over the network, and 'unpacking' it, so that it can access all of the information that it holds.

The intention is that my program will look at what information each PDU holds, and if any of them hold information that meets a specified criteria, it will re-package them, and send them out over another network.

Currently, I am able to get/ set things such as entity type, location, etc. When looking at the [DIS Data Dictionary](http://faculty.nps.edu/brutzman/vrtp/mil/navy/nps/disenumerations/jdbehtmlfiles/pdu/29.htm), I see that an Entity State PDU has a field called 'Alternate Entity Type', and that there is a PDU component called 'Alternative Entity Type Record', which are things that would be really useful for the work that I am doing.

However, I can't seem to find a method that will allow to set/ get these values at all when programming in Java... I am able to set the entity type (not alternative entity type) using methods such as:

```
EntityID eid = espdu.getEntityID():
eid.setSite(12);
eid.setApplication(34);
eid.setEntity(56);
```

so I would expect to be able to set the alternative entity type using methods such as:

```
eid.setAlternateSite(78);
eid.setAlternateApplication(90);
```

etc. But these methods do not seem to exist... Does anyone know how I can set the alternative values for the entity type? Or is this something from an older version of DIS, and no longer available in the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

Just realised what I'm doing wrong- I'm trying to set the alternative details from `eid`, which is an `EntityID` variable- I should be setting them directly from the `EntityStatePdu` variable.